# How do I generate an initial/base migration for existing Symfony+Doctrine application?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

If I already use migrations, I can easily generate incremental one using:
`app/console doctrine:migrations:diff`.

But assume I have an existing application that does not use migrations yet. `doctrine:migrations:diff` will just generate a diff between the current database schema and doctrine entities. The problem is I need to have an initial/first migration consisting of `CREATE TABLE` for every entity created up to this point. My current workaround is to create an empty database, switch credentials in `parameters.yml`, and run `doctrine:migrations:diff` then.

I don't like this solution - is there a better one?

Comment: Why don't you create an initial SQL which is gonna be run in the first migration with the table CREATIONS without the INSERTS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could use doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql to generate the sql for creation and put this into the first migration version

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#database-schema-generation

Answer (score 4):

And what about a little :

```bash
bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff --from-empty-schema
```

With the flag **--from-empty-schema** it will do exactly what you're asking for.

After that you can (must) manually add an entry in the `doctrine_migration_versions` table if the DB is already set up and you want to (have to) run `/bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`. Like that (screenshot from adminer):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the table does not exist as a Doctrine Entity, you'll need to manually create a migration class for it, as well as any separate Fixtures.

```
<?php

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use DoctrineDBALMigrationsAbstractMigration,
DoctrineDBALSchemaSchema;

class Version00001 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE MY_CUSTOM_PREFIX_example (id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema)
    {
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE MY_CUSTOM_PREFIX_example');
    }
}
```

Also make sure that you exclude these custom tables using filters within your Doctrine configuration (@see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#manual-tables)

For this example you'd replace `t_` with `MY_CUSTOM_PREFIX_`

Comment: @siergiej please vote it valid if helped to guide others to follow the same way